# ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. ) Docker IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, docker, iis-10

Getting error while running a docker container created by below file

```
FROM microsoft/iis

RUN mkdir C:\site

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    Import-module IISAdministration; \
    New-IISSite -Name "Site" -PhysicalPath C:\site -BindingInformation "*:8080:"

Add dist\ C:\site 

ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = 1

EXPOSE 80
```

Then:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 app-temp1
```

`ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )
Applied configuration changes to section "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"`

Answer (score 1):

According to this post, it is by design:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/35

On a docker IIS, you can only use the default AppPool.